# how to remove a item from json column use postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

version = 9.5.5

Now I have a column named info, like this:

```
[{"id":1, "name":"car"},{"id":2, "name":"bus"}]
```

I want to remove {"id":2, "name":"bus"} which id = 2, instead of info::jsonb - 1,not by index but the key-value, so how can I do that? thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
select jsonb_agg(e.value) from (
    select '[{"id":1, "name":"car"},{"id":2, "name":"bus"}]'::jsonb as data
) a, jsonb_array_elements(a.data) e
where e.value->>'id' <> '2'
```